# apply lambda or define a function to return 1 else 0 in dask dataframe

Tags: python, function, lambda, dask-dataframe

Probably easy, but I am still learning.

I am creating a new column in dask dataframe where the value will come from after extracting the last four str characters of `date` column in str ddmmyyyy.
What I did:

1. have is a list of inv_years
2. extract the lst four characters of the string date
3. tried to define a function that if the extracted years are in the inv_years list, return 1 else 0 in a new column.

Issue: How do I write a working function or better in fewer lines a lambda function

```
def valid_yr(x):
    inv_years = ['1921','1969','2026','2030','2041','2060','2062']
    validity_year = ddf['string_ddmmyyyy'].str[-4:] #extract the last four to get the year
    if validity_year.isin(inv_years): 
        x = 1
    else:
        x = 0
    return x

#create a new column and apply function
ddf['validity_year']= ??? # what to write here?
```

Answer (score 0):

A very grumpy way I could come up with is

```
inv_years = ['1921','1969','2026','2030','2041','2060','2062']
ddf['validity_year'] = ddf.apply(lambda row: 1 if row.string_ddmmyyyy[-4:] in inv_years else 0, axis=1)
```

or to try and get your approach working we initially modify your function a bit so as it's argument is a single row.

```
def valid_yr(row):
    inv_years = ['1921','1969','2026','2030','2041','2060','2062']
    validity_year = row.string_ddmmyyyy[-4:]
    if validity_year in inv_years:
        x = 1
    else:
        x = 0
    return x
```

Now we can apply this function to all rows.

```
ddf['validity_year'] = ddf.apply(valid_yr, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, IIUC, for this: `ddf['validity_year'] = ddf.apply(valid_yr, axis=1)` I modified it to `ddf['validity_year'] = ddf['source_column'].apply(valid_yr, axis=1)`. Thanks for correcting if it was a mistake. When I applied it, I got Value and Type error. For ValueError, it is asking for the meta= keyword. For the TypeError, `TypeError("valid_yr() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'")`

Comment: Could you clearly state the errors you were facing ?